# Can I use one line initialization of a blank address and have validation

Tags: angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I recently started working with Angular 2 and reactive forms. What I'm trying to accomplish is simple: create an array inside a form and let user push new objects into it (say list of user addresses to which user can add new addresses - standard FormArray). That's quite simple (and it's all described well in the documentation) but I'd like to be able to automatically validate user's input as well. I know I can do this by simply pushing a group like this:

```
this.formBuilder.group({
    country: ['', Validators.required],
    city: ['', Validators.required],
    ...
})
```

but I've got a model that represents an address instance and I would like to use it like that:

```
this.formBuilder.group(new Address())
```

that's actually how I do it right now (without validation).

My question is: can I use this one line initialization of a blank address and somehow have the validation without explicitly defining my validators every time I push new blank address?

If my question isn't clear enough, I'll answer all of your questions.

Comment: you need to validate manually ?..

Answer (score 0):

This could be an option for you:

```
this.formBuilder.group(new Address(),
                       {validator: (fg: FormGroup) => this.attachValidators(fg)})
```

Basically setting a custom validator, which goes through the individual controls of the address collection and sets their individual validators property as desired. See below:

```
//helper method
private attachValidators(address: FormGroup)/*: ValidationErrors */ {
    for (let ctrlName of Object.keys(address.controls)) {
        address.get(ctrlName).setValidators(Validators.required);
    }
}
```

May be too much, if you consider the repetitive assignment of validators

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer